# smarty in_array on template

Tags: smarty, minishop2

Как сделать в smarty

```
if in_array($a, array(1,2,3))
```

То есть массив не в переменной, а задать строго.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если smarty версии 3, то например так:

```
{$ids = [1, 2, 3]}
{if in_array($id, $ids)}
```

Или даже так (но не уверен):

```
{if in_array($id, [1, 2, 3])}
```